# Foreach loop Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3, sms-gateway

*This is the my code i tried*

```
foreach ($data2 as $row){
    $hp=$data3[$row['NoHP']];
    $result = "https://reguler.zenziva.net/apps/smsapi.php?userkey=asdasads&passkey=dhdgfhdfh&nohp='$hp'&pesan='test'";
    simplexml_load_file($result);
}
```

I want to loop sending message using the API, but the phone number is `result_array` which I take from model.  How can I enter the phone number to the URI by looping?   How can I send message as many phone numbers as I get?

[image]

Comment: Please do not put code as images in your question.  Paste the code as text and use the editor to format is as code (the { } icon on top.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `$row['NoHP']` if it contains mobile number like this:

```
foreach ($data2 as $row)
{
   $hp = $data3[$row['NoHP']];
   $result = "https://reguler.zenziva.net/apps/smsapi.php?userkey=asdasads&passkey=dhdgfhdfh&nohp=".$row['NoHP']."&pesan='test'";
   simplexml_load_file($result);
}
```